# Cannot display data using DOMDocument and xpath, why?

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domxpath

I'm trying to get data from 17track.net, i mean when i tracking a number i got the result in the result box, but i can't display it in my file.

this is my code:

```
<?php
//RA190265307CN is the tracking number 

$result = array();
$classname = "tb-stat";
$domdocument = new DOMDocument();
$domdocument->loadHTMLFile('http://www.17track.net/en/result/post.shtml?nums=RA190265307CN');
$a = new DOMXPath($domdocument);
$spans = $a->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");

for ($i = $spans->length - 1; $i > -1; $i--) {
    $result[] = $spans->item($i)->firstChild->nodeValue;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);    ?>
```

Thats the result of the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
)
```

Whats wrong with my code? I'm trying to get the "Status" of the tracking number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `firstChild` will select a child `<colgroup>` which is empty. 
I think you want to replace

```
$result[] = $spans->item($i)->firstChild->nodeValue;
```

by

```
$result[] = $spans->item($i)->nodeValue;
```

This currently returns

```
Not Found(0) / Transporting(0) / Pick Up(0) / Delivered(0)
```

If you want to descend into this string even further you can take advantage of the fact that the status values `"(0)"` are braced in `<em>` tags. So, for example changing yout XPATH expression to

```
$query = "//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]//em";
```

will select the individual status and put them into the array `result`. Using the index `0..3` you will be able to randomly access the status. If you want to have a numeric value you will still have to extract it from the string.

Comment: True, thanks for that. When I'm trying to get just the number status (delivered, transporting, etc..) the array return empty results.. the status Class is "s-packState", I checked that with firebug. What's wrong?

Comment: So you want an array of the four strings "(0)"?

Comment: I try to take the correct status of the package, "Not Found(0) / **Transporting(1)** / Pick Up(0) / Delivered(0)", this is the code i wrote:
http://pastebin.com/xk1yP7yL

The result is fine (i'm think), but how i get just the status (in this case- Transporting)?

Comment: Not really true, always one status will be value "(1)", (like Transporting **(1)** ), your xpath query is really good but the array always return [0] => (0). What i want to do is [0] => Transporting. / [0] => Delivered.. etc.. **How?** Because statuses themselves (not their values​​) is not stored in any tag.

Comment: True but still have a problem. All the values in the array are "(0)", My guess it's because the request is sent to 17track before 17track finishes load the ajax, the value of the status changes only after the ajax load.. How to fix this?